# How to programatically retrieve file that is on a web page using java

Tags: java, url

I am trying to download a file (which I believe is an Application/OCTET-STREAM attachment) from a web page.
The URL looks like http://REDACTED.com/bb/avfile/filename. When I enter this Url in a browser (IE or Firefox) the file downloads normally, with a size of 72KB, with no file extension and can be opened with my spreadsheet program . When I try to download the file through my java program it retrieves a file of only 70KB which will not open in my spreadsheet program. Trying to parse the file with  org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.* produces an error of " Package should contain a content type part [M1.13]" which makes sense to me as the file is smaller that the file downloading from the Browser

It seems the server will only deliver the correct file if the URL request is comming from a browser. Here is my code:

```
String UrlString = "http://REDACTED.com/bb/avfile/filename";
URL internetURL = new URL(UrlString);
URLConnection internetConnection = internetURL.openConnection();

destinationFile = new File(filePath + "test");
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyURLToFile (internetURL, destinationFile,2000,2000);
```

I have tried casting to an httpConnection

```
HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(UrlString).openConnection();
httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
```

I have tried setting the setRequestProperty methods to match the headers to what is shown in HTTPFOX when i submit the URL throught the browserlike so :

```
httpConnection.setRequestProperty ("Content-Type","application/vnd.ms-excel");
httpConnection.setRequestProperty ("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:9.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0.1");
// etc,
```

Also getting the file as a stream :

```
destinationFile = new File(filePath + "temp2");
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile
(httpConnection.getInputStream(), destinationFile);
```

All methods produce a file that is 2KB smaller than the file downloaded from the browser. The only difference I can see is the headers from the browser as shown by HTTPFox shows the request line as "bb/avfile/filenameHTTP1.1" with the host being "REDACTED.com". Adding HTTP1.1 to the URL in either the browser or through the program, produces a 1K file that reads "av content requested is not available". HTTPFox shows that there are no POST requests

I am at a loss as to how to proceed . Any Suggestions or ideas on what problem is ?

Comment: Use firefox's `Live http header` addon and show us the `header info` (all the request's made) when you manually try to download the file.

Comment: I doubt any of these will create a 70K file instead of 72K

Comment: Following are the headers from Live HTTP Headers (which is the same info from HTTPFox) :

Answer (score 0):

This could be possible (happened to me and nobody believed me...) because there maybe thing in the HTML that request additional HTML. But for a small difference of 2kb this is unlikely the case. I suspect that your workflow is relying on some "quirks" in HTML rendering. Also going from HTML->OFFICE is a bad bad idea unless you clean the HTML.

I would try to clean the HTML with JSOUP and see if you can open the output. You want a simple table, right? What features are you hoping to extract from the HTML?

Try these

1. Try using wget. Verify that the file retrieved with wget is the desired size. If it not the desired size (wget=>70kb, you_want=>72kb), then indeed somekind of relevant changes are being made in the browser.
2. If it works in wget you are stripping some of the HTML with your java-side serialization. This shouldn't be a problem and indicates a problem with your workflow.
3. If it doesn't work with wget. This means that the browser is "fixing" the HTML. If this is the case then you should identify what you need fixed and what the browser is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Following are the headers from Live HTTP Headers (which is the same info from HTTPFox) : 
 http://media.bloomberg.com/bb/avfile/rmjBGqgXkPnk

GET /bb/avfile/rmjBGqgXkPnk HTTP/1.1
Host: media.bloomberg.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:9.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: opt=no-opt; bdfpc=001.3585249025.1322666901; companypage_tm1=1322666901; companypage=1; __utma=30057196.1103067570.1328849418.1329111755.1329116018.8; __utmz=30057196.1328850070.2.2.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided); s_vi=[CS]v1|276B25CB851D18E9-4000012F600000A2[CE]; rsi_segs=K05539_10802|K05539_10672|K05539_10444|K05539_10784|K05539_10785|K05539_10632|K05539_10562|K05539_10694|K05539_10284|K05539_10561|K05539_10807|K05539_10668|K05539_10698|K05539_10635|K05539_10645|K05539_10541|K05539_10712|K05539_10585|K05539_10522|K05539_10426|K05539_10384|K05539_10315|K05539_10520|K05539_10429|K05539_10507|K05539_10497|K05539_10466|K05539_10365|K05539_10434|K05539_10451|K05539_10160|K05539_10474|K05539_10479|K05539_10480|K05539_10481|K05539_10491|K05539_10495|K05539_10499|K05539_10366|K05539_10529|K05539_10545|K05539_10136|K05539_10301|K05539_10582|K05539_10591|K05539_10592|K05539_10005|K05539_10627|K05539_10647|K05539_10648|K05539_10682|K05539_10721|K05539_10751|K05539_10758|K05539_10761|K05539_10792|K05539_10793; agent_id=1d547385-fe3b-4fdd-847e-15d60dff617c; session_id=b2fa2002-70b5-44c2-b0b7-a10cb53ff6df; session_key=91363212-f200-5a96-a2d7-a8ddabdbf214; __utmx=30057196.00013155880168891469:4:17; __utmxx=30057196.00013155880168891469:1322673451:2592000; quintTrack=7339626780942826; __qca=P0-1259442857-1322673325742; morestories201112_tm=1323712414; morestories201112=rsch23; oo_inv_reprompt=1; VWCUKP300=L0/Q87869_16825_75_020712_1_022912_526278x525869x020712x1x1; hprec201202_tm=1328848822; hprec201202=rd7; __utmv=30057196.|1=recommendation_cookie=rd7=1^2=morestories201112=rsch23=1^4=companypages=1=1^7=recommendation_cookie=rd7=1; cobdfpc=010.3213488906.1329116155

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Sun-Java-System-Web-Server/7.0
Date: Tue, 14 Feb 2012 05:11:34 GMT
Last-Modified: Tue, 14 Feb 2012 05:05:34 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel
Content-Encoding: gzip
Edge-Control: !no-store,max-age=3d
Cache-Control: max-age=86400
Expires: Wed, 15 Feb 2012 05:11:34 GMT

### Content-Length: 70743

This downloads a file which can be opened with Open Office Calc program (a spreadsheet program). I am not sure what Mishas answer is trying to tell me as I am not interacting with any HTML - just entering the http:// address in the URL box of the browser.

Comment: Please add these to the question itself, not as an answer

Comment: Sorry, I am new here. How do I do that ? Using Edit on the original question didn't seem appropriate at the time but maybe that is the correct procedure ?

Comment: Yes, editing is the way. You may add this info as an update to the question (this is how others do it).